# Android: Simple way to make a whole a tap to skip page?

Tags: android

I have a disclaimer on a page and I want to make it so that the user can tap the page and it will launch the new activity. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you try onTouchEvent for your activity or use singletap listeners

Comment: If your disclaimer page is an Activity then @Andro is right you can just apply an OnTouchListener to the top level View in your Layout. then in the onTouch() you can call finish(), or hide the disclaimer view.

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html and specifically the section "Using JavaScript in WebView". From that javascript interface you can send an intent to the desired activity. Hopes this helps!